# QIODevice Write at End

Tags: c++, c, qt, qiodevice

I have the following setup,

```
audio_output = new QAudioOutput(*audio_format, this);
audio_device = audio_output->start(); // Return QIODevice
audio_device->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

I need a function that writes data to the end of the audio_device stream whilst it's playing. The problem is that as it's playing, it's changing the pos (tested this). I need to call,

```
audio_device->write(buffer, byte - buffer);
```

To write to the end of the written buffer. How can I have it play and write at the same time?

Many thanks for any help here.

**__*Edit*__**

Partial fix! It makes a slight crackle.

```
while (audio_device->write(buffer, byte - buffer) < 1)
    usleep(10);
```

Looks like it was failing to write the buffer. Is there a nicer way to do that?

Comment: Can try to feed in an [QBuffer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qbuffer.html) to [QAudioOutput::start(QIODevice * device)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qaudiooutput.html#start);  From that, you should be able to stream data into the buffer instead of using audio_device's write().

Comment: Wouldn't that still write at the position of the read?

Comment: I expect that adding/appending to the buffer would not interrupt the play-back - it's worth trying.

Comment: That doesn't produce any output now. :S I used [link](http://pastebin.com/LsqYdwud)

Comment: Would an empty buffer cause the audio_device to cease play-back?  Can you make sure that there's data in the buffer before calling start()?

Comment: Empty data definitely stops the playback. Infact, I get a buffer underflow error. The issue is when the audio output reads, it changes the pos() in the audio_device, so when I write, I write exactly where it's reading. The result is garbled sounds at random points through the song for a second, then nothing.

Comment: Ahhh, Sounds like you may have to implement some buffer "slices" (i.e. fragments) that you can feed to the audio_device when the it reaches the end of the current buffer - not sure how seamless this will be though - I haven't dealt with streaming data